# Url rewriting in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to rewrite the url

```
http://localhost:56713/Home/UserDetails?Code=223322
```

with

```
http://localhost:56713/223322
```

I have written below in StartUp.cs but it is not working

```
var rewrite = new RewriteOptions()
  .AddRewrite(@"{$1}", "Home/UserDetails?Code={$1}",true);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a Regular Expression on the first parameter on AddRewrite function.

```
var rewrite = new RewriteOptions().AddRewrite(
     @"^Home/UserDetails?Code=(.*)",  // RegEx to match Route
     "Home/{$1}",                     // URL to rewrite route
     skipRemainingRules: true         // Should skip other rules
);
```

This link maybe can help with more examples
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Answer (score 1):

Adding a rule to match `@"{$1}"` won't work. The term `$1` represents a value parsed using RegEx. You haven't executed any RegEx so you're effectively telling it to "rewrite my URL whenever the URL is `null`". Clearly, that isn't very likely.

You want to match the incoming URL using this regular expression:

```
@"^Home/UserDetails?Code=(\d+)"
```

The `(\d+)` tells RegEx to match "one or more digits" and store it as a variable. Since this is the only variable included in the parens, the value is stored in `$1`.

You then want to rewrite the URL using the value parsed using that regex:

```
"Home/$1"
```

You pass these two strings into the `AddRewrite` method:

```
AddRewrite(
    @"^Home/UserDetails?Code=(\d+)", // RegEx to match URL
    "Home/$1", // URL to rewrite
    true // Stop processing any aditional rules
);
```

Comment: Thank you.What is the RegEx when the querystring is like '(abc) - xyz @ 123'